# How to make Thunderbird Mail runs at startup?

Tags: startup, thunderbird

Is that possible that I can make Thunderbird Mail app runs at the startup or as soon as I log into my Ubuntu? This is my first time using Ubuntu, I create a Dual Boot Ubuntu and I learn about Linux from my Introduction to Linus course at my college. I hope I can learn a lot here about Linux/Ubuntu as I am sick of Windows. Thanks.

Comment: [How to start Thunderbird minimized on start-up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169437/how-to-start-thunderbird-minimized-on-start-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 14.04, simply add thunderbird to Startup Programs, accessed from the Dash.

[image]

Comment: Hey Organic Marble. It works!! Thanks. I am curious, why such an easy add makes the Thunderbird Mail start on startup? What's behind the Conky? Can you explain to me briefly? Thanks.

Comment: Conky is a neat program that lets you display system monitor type information on your desktop.  People really go wild with it and make some really cool displays.  I have it in my startups so it runs every time.  Here is more info about conky: http://devmadness.com/os-software/conky-themes-scripts-configs/