# notification for new mail in ubuntu 18.04 with thunderbird and pop3 accounts

Tags: 18.04, email, thunderbird, notification, gnome-shell

Is there a (recommended) way to activate notifications for new mails with Ubuntu 18.04 and Thunderbird (POP3 **not** IMAP)?

I've found some guides in the net, but they are all for older versions of Ubuntu or marked as deprecated or experimental. And the gnome online account app does not support POP3 (only IMAP).

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Good question. Previously I have used Popper (now obsolete, but I have forced it to work on [14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/965158/66509) and [16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/965156/66509)). You can [try MailNag](https://askubuntu.com/a/824975/66509). Or may be some new GNOME Shell Extension...

Comment: FYI I have tested Popper on 18.04 LTS running MATE and Unity - it works. If this is what you want - then you can follow [my guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/965156/66509).

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert. I've tried [mailnag](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag) plus [mailnag-gnome-shell](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag-gnome-shell). This is a decent solution for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to try [MailNag](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag).

> **An extensible mail notification daemon**
>
> Mailnag is a daemon program that checks POP3 and IMAP servers for new mail.
>   On mail arrival it performs various actions provided by plugins.
>   Mailnag comes with a set of desktop-independent default plugins for
>   visual/sound notifications, script execution etc. and can be extended
>   with additional plugins easily.

You can install it from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Epulb/+archive/mailnag) with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pulb/mailnag
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mailnag
```

If you need intergration with desktop then

- for GNOME Shell install [`gnome-shell-mailnag`](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag-gnome-shell)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-mailnag
  ```
- if you use GNOME Online Accounts in GNOME Shell then install [`mailnag-goa-plugin`](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag-goa-plugin)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mailnag-goa-plugin
  ```
- for modern Unity, MATE, Xfce, Pantheon Elementary install [`mailnag-messagingmenu-plugin`](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag-messagingmenu-plugin)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mailnag-messagingmenu-plugin
  ```
- for Cinnamon use instruction from [`mailnagapplet`](https://bitbucket.org/hyOzd/mailnagapplet).

**Note:** Some packages are currently not available for 18.04 LTS, but I have contacted the developer to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `MailSpring` from ubuntu software