# How to emulate pressing the Close button from a script?

Tags: scripts, thunderbird

I wanted **Thunderbird** to stay in the Background to notify me of incoming mails.

After a bit of searching, I found this post.
[How to keep Thunderbird and Pidgin running on background?](https://askubuntu.com/a/126853/67346)

The solution is to install an addon so that when we close Thunderbird it just stays in the background.

Now, to have thunderbird running at Start up we can just add it to `Startup Applications`.

But, when I open my system, `Thunderbird` also gets opened and I have to manually press the close button everytime to make Thunderbird go into the background.

The solution given in the [above post](https://askubuntu.com/a/126853/67346) for this problem is to select `Minimize on start`. But doing so affects the way in which Thunderbird works when invoked from the Messaging menu. So I deselected this option.

But, if there is a way to emulate pressing the Close button from a script, I can just add that script to `Startup Applications`

So is there a way to achieve this?

**Note :** If there is a simpler way to solve my original problem of keeping Thunderbird in background please post that also.

Many thanks.

Comment: According to the link you gave, the extension "Minimize On Start and Close" provides the option to minimise on open. Have you tried that? Regarding a simpler way, I just put Thunderbird on a different workspace!

Comment: Forgot to add this. If we select `Minimize on start` then while pressing the mail entry in the Messaging menu, Thunderbird does not open up properly. I need to once again go and press the Thunderbird icon. So, I removed `Minimize on start` option.

Comment: Edited the question,the explain the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [probable absence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Command_Line_Options) of a `Thunderbird` command-line option that you could use to start it minimized or in the background, your best option is probably to use something like `xdotool`, which is in the repositories. (See my later note on the [minimize to tray addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/)).

This is the command you need to minimise the instance of `Thunderbird`; `xdotool` searches for the `Thunderbird` window on the window stack and then minimizes it

```
xdotool search --class thunderbird windowminimize %@
```

Maximise Thunderbird and then try it in the terminal; it seems to be the command you are looking for. Often when used in scripts the `--sync` argument is added, as noted in the man page:

> After requesting the window minimize, wait until the window is actually minimized. This is useful for scripts that depend on actions being completed before moving on.

You may also have to delay the command a bit until Thunderbird has actually started up, and there is a sleep command built into `xdotool`, so you could use

```
xdotool sleep 6 search --class thunderbird windowminimize %@
```

and set the sleep interval at whatever value you needed.

This minimises `Thunderbird`, but not to the background like when you use the [minimize to tray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) addon, as you set up that addon so that pressing exit sends `Thunderbird` to the tray. Assuming that addon is installed, it may be possible to use `xdotool` to emulate the mouse-click of the x in Thunderbird's window and so background it. However, using `windowkill` instead of `windowminimize` with `Thunderbird` (when the tray addon is installed) closes the entire application.

---

After discussion it was said that the `windowunmap` option was the one necessary to actually hide the window; this is much easier than trying to emulate a click on the thunderbird window.

```
xdotool sleep 6 search --class thunderbird windowunmap %@
```

Comment: +1, This is such an awesome tool. Hopefully I should be able to find a way to use this tool to emulate a close click. Will try it out and get back

Comment: @Karthik Yes, it is a great tool- I'll see if I can do it for you as well- it should be possible.

Comment: The `windowunmap` option did the trick. The command will be like `xdotool sleep 6 search --class thunderbird windowunmap %@`

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the info in my previous comment.

Comment: @Karthik Yes, I have done the edit, and I'll also see if it's possible to do it it by simulating a mouse-click. Thanks.

Comment: From what I have seen so far mouse clicks take only x, y coordinates. This means that I have to find the position of the Close button. Anyways, I will read up more and see if this is possible.

Comment: +1, Great job @Milk and @Karthik!! Can I update my answer in the **How to keep Thunderbird and Pidgin running on background?** question with your solution? Just to have a complete answer to that question! (if you matter about askubuntu points I'll point back to this question with a link!!)

Comment: @naskoos Thanks. Yes, that's fine- just link it for reference.